# How to inflate textView as layout

Tags: android, textview, android-arrayadapter, layout-inflater

I have been trying to inflate the below xml file but not having a luck,kindly point me to the right direction.I need to inflate and then add it to my array adapter.

```
        TextView footerView = null;
        View row = null;



        if (null == footerView) {

            LayoutInflater inflater =  getLayoutInflater();
            row =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view,null);
            footerView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.footerView);
            setContentView(footerView);


            return;
        }


        getListView().addFooterView(footerView);


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/footerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/add_new_todo_item_string"
    android:textSize="24sp" >

</TextView>
```

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "not having a luck" means.

Comment: I am trying to display this on the emulator scree.                               add_new_todo_item_string

Comment: With setContentView you are resetting all the view of the activity, so getListView cannot do anything

Comment: So how do I return the listview to the user.

Comment: post the whole adapter class code, there's not enough here to see what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

***Resolved***
The below code has worked and solved my problem

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, getListView(), false);
    footerView = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.footerView);

    // TODO - Add footerView to ListView

    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);
```